# Reading file in Fortran-90 written out by Python f.write()

Tags: python, arrays, fortran90, read-write

So someone wrote this code which outputs x,y,z positions of some particles.

```
    if rs.contains_block(file+'.hdf5',"POS ",parttype=1):
        d1 = rs.read_block(file, "POS ",parttype=1,verbose=False)
        blocksize = struct.pack('I', len(d1)*8*3)
        f.write(blocksize)
        for i in range(len(d1)):
            for j in range(3):
                data = struct.pack('d',d1[i][j])
                f.write(data)
        f.write(blocksize)
        print 'Position real', d1, k
    else:
        data = struct.pack('I',0)
        f.write(data)
        f.write(data)
```

Or basically:

```
        for i = 1:Nparticles
             for j = 1:3
                write xyz[i][j]
             end
        end
```

Now I am trying to read this back in F90 like:

```
  real*4,   allocatable :: pos(:,:)
  N=sum(Nparticles)
  open (1, file=filename, form='unformatted')
  allocate(pos(1:3,1:N))
  read (1) pos
  close(1)
```

When I print the first three rows I get:

```
  do i =1,3
      print *, pos(1:3,i)
  end do

  >>   0.00000000       2.61613369      -2.00000000    
       1.88289821      -2.00000000       1.96834707    
       2.00000000       2.61616445       2.00000000
```

Now I know for certain that the positions range from 0 - 25 so getting -2.0000 everywhere is concerning. Is there something about my friends Python write out (f.write()) that that I need to tell Fortran to do during the read in so it outputs the positions correctly? Leading characters? Allocation correction? I've used a Python read-in and I get the following for the first 3 entries:

```
 >>> pos = rs.read_block("filename","POS ",parttype=1)
 >>> pos(1:3,:)
    array([[ 12.49398994,  21.89432526,   6.23691988],
           [ 12.48858261,  21.89297867,   6.23258686],
           [ 12.48777962,  21.89576149,   6.23423147],
```

Which is not what I get when I do the Fortran read in above.

Thanks.

Comment: The 'd' character format of the python struct module is for double precision floating point values, which use 8 bytes.  Try changing `real*4` to `real*8`.

Comment: Warren, people like you make this world a better place. Thank-you.

Comment: Though, why does pos(1:3,:) only output 6 decimal places if it is assigned in python as a real*8? Is this automatically truncated upon output?

Comment: Where do you see 6 decimal places?

Comment: I'm blind sorry. Ok - no more questions. Thanks again.